# C# program always crash when creating Windows Media Encoder object

Tags: c#, .net, windows, media, encoder

I am using Windows Vista x86 + VSTS 2008. When creating new Windows Media Encoder object using statement

WMEncoder encoder = new WMEncoder();

My program always crash in VSTS 2008. Here is the screen snapshot. Any ideas what is wrong?

http://i40.tinypic.com/2v96uqo.jpg

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: I think you have to debug and display what is the type of exception/stacktrace

Comment: Can I debug inside Windows Media SDK? It does not ship with source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem may be in Windows Media Encoder: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929182

You might just have to update WME for this to work. As a test, you might try this on XP to see if it works - if so, it's likely the WME version on Vista.

This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493069/wmencoder-issue

Comment: The hotfix seems describing the issue I met with -- crash when creating new encoder object instance, but when I install the hot fix, after installation successful from installation wizard, the Wmenceng.dll DLL versions are still 9.0.0.2980, not 9.0.0.3352.

Comment: I have tested your solution works, cool! I have marked as your reply as answer.

Comment: I have a related question here,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843100/how-to-improve-my-code-to-make-better-video-quality

Appreciated if you could share some of your points. :-)